# How do I send a .js command from the terminal to a website?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, chromium, javascript

I'd like to access these things from terminal:

1. Open a page in Chromium
2. Execute a JavaScript command (like these in the console, when you click on "Inspect element")
3. Kill the page.

How do I send the JavaScript command from the terminal to the page?